# Error Swagger Ambiguous HTTP method for action

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, http-delete

i need to know why occurs the next situation and if exists a different solution:

Actually my Api has an error when with Swagger use in method controller a HttpDelete action and Route decoration:

```
[Route("delete/{id}"), HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSession(string id)
{   //... any code
}
```

[image]

Actually i **only resolve the error when erase the Route decoration**:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSession(string id)
{ //... any code}
```

[image]

**I want to know why occurs this error ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
[Route("delete/{id}"), HttpDelete("{id}")]
```

To this:

```
[HttpDelete, Route("{id}")]
```

The way you *were* doing it defines the route twice... both times differently, which causes conflicts.

Comment: Yes, i put [HttpDelete, Route("delete/{id}")]